# cvCaptureFromCAM program creates segmentation faults only some of the time

Tags: c++, gcc, opencv, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-12.04

I've been kicking around with OpenCV 2.4.3 and a Logitech C920 camera hoping to get a primitive sort of facial recognition scheme going. Very simple, not very sophisticated.

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"


#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/** Function Headers */
void grabcurrentuser();
void capturecurrentuser( Mat vsrc );

/** Global Variables **/
string face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;

int main( void ){//[main]
    grabcurrentuser();

}//]/main]

void grabcurrentuser(){//[grabcurrentuser]
    CvCapture* videofeed;
    Mat videoframe;

    //Load face cascade
    if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){
        printf("Can't load haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml\n");
    }
    //Read from source video feed for current user
    videofeed = cvCaptureFromCAM( 1 );
    if( videofeed ){
            for(int i=0; i<10;i++){//Change depending on platform
            videoframe = cvQueryFrame( videofeed );

            //Debug source videofeed with display
            if( !videoframe.empty() ){
            imshow( "Source Video Feed", videoframe ); 
            //Perform face detection on videoframe
            capturecurrentuser( videoframe );
        }else{ 
            printf("Videoframe is empty or error!!!"); break; 
        }

            int c = waitKey(33);//change to increase or decrease delay between frames
            if( (char)c == 'q' ) { break; }

            }
    }
}//[/grabcurrentuser]

void capturecurrentuser( Mat vsrc ){//[capturecurrentuser]
    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat vsrc_gray;
    Mat currentuserface;

    //Preprocess frame for face detection
    cvtColor( vsrc, vsrc_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    equalizeHist( vsrc_gray, vsrc_gray );

    //Find face
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale( vsrc_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30,30) );
    //Take face and crop out into a Mat
    currentuserface = vsrc_gray( faces[0] );
    //Save the mat into a jpg file on disk
    imwrite( "currentuser.jpg", currentuserface );
    //Show saved image in a window  
    imshow( "Current User Face", currentuserface ); 

}//[/capturecurrentuser]
```

The above code is the first component of this system. It's job is to accept the video feed, take 10 frames or so (hence the for loop) and run a haar cascade on the frames to obtain a face. Once a face is acquired, it cuts that face out into a Mat and saves it as a jpg in the working directory.

It's worked so far, but seems to be a very tempermental piece of code. It's giving me the desired output most of the time (I don't intend to ask here how I can make things more accurate or precise - but feel free to tell me :D) but other times it ends in a segmentation fault. The following is an example of normal output (i've looked around and seen that the VIDIOC invalid argument is something that can be ignored - again, if its an easy fix feel free to tell me) with the segmentation fault.

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
init done 
opengl support available 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Can anyone tell me why sometimes with concurrent runs of this program I run into a single or series of segmentation fault results like above, and other times not? This program is designed to create an output thats shunted off to another program I wrote, so I can't have it seizing up on me like this.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Have you pinpointed the function call that causes the crash?

Comment: The error is coming from this like:  videofeed = cvCaptureFromCAM( 1 ); ... I am currently trying to figure out the issue with similar code.

Comment: Please use the newer `VideoCapture` and other C++ implementations. As for the segmentation fault, it seems to because your camera is not initialised or ready. Check for v4l and opengl drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the following line:

```
currentuserface = vsrc_gray( faces[0] );
```

From my experience segmentation faults arise when you are accessing stuff that does not exist.
The program works fine if a face is detected because faces[0] contains data. However, when no face is detected (cover the camera), no rectangle is stored in faces[0]. Thus the error occurs.

Try initialising like this, so that imshow and imwrite works when nothing is detected:

```
cv::Mat currentuserface = cv::Mat::zeros(vsrc.size(), CV_8UC1);
```

and then check if faces is empty before you initialize currentuserface with it:

```
if( !faces.empty() )

currentuserface = vsrc_gray( faces[0] );
```